# R Color the largest bar of a barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

Is it possible to color the largest bar of a barplot using R ?

**Data :**

```
count<-c(a=5,b=7,c=8,d=4,e=8,f=4)
barplot(count)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, although in this case two bars get colored because they are both equal to the max value.

```
maxfac <- 1+(count==max(count))
maxfac
## a b c d e f 
## 1 1 2 1 2 1 
barplot(count,col=c("black","red")[maxfac])
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i want !